# can we send two types of files in a single flow file in Apache nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have made a custom processor which converts a Excel workbook in JSON and output it but i want that workbook and JSON both in Output. Is it Possible?

Answer (score 2):

The content of a flow file is just bytes, you could put whatever you want in it assuming that something downstream knows how to understand the combination of an Excel workbook and a JSON file.

A more common approach is for a processor to have multiple relationships, one would be "original" which is where you would transfer the original input to the processor, in this case the Excel workbook, and the other would be "success" where you would transfer the successfully created JSON, and then maybe a "failure" relationship where you would transfer the Excel workbook if you couldn't create the JSON for some reason.